# Is "I can want" proper english? Does it sound ok for natives?

Tags: usage, word-order, sentence-usage

For example, in sentences like "I can want whatever I want", or "I can want something now and still change my mind about it later".

Or are there better ways to say this? Google shows plenty of results but it still sounds wrong to me, somehow.

Comment: "I can want" by itself is not idiomatic, but your other sentences sound just fine. It will make your question better if you use the [edit] link to explain why it sounds wrong to you. Can explain exactly what you are trying to say, but in other words? That might make it clear.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks for the feedback. As for why it sounds wrong to me, I can't quite put my finger on it. I guess maybe it's just not something I've heard a lot, so it sticks out.

Comment: @P.E.Dant You're comment is the correct answer.  You should write it as the answer instead of a comment.